# Which sensor for rotating android?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Hi which sensor(s) would I need to manage for my joystick app to capture the  following movement;

Device is in landscape, held in front of you with both hands with the device tilted forward towards TV i.e. somewhat gamepad like.

Now push or pull left or right edge of device away or towards you.

Thanks,

Comment: You would need the gyroscope. Is that your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the accelerometer sensor to capture the x, y and z position of device

Comment: Actually, I think the asker describing a rotation motion, so the accelerometer wouldn't help much.